# jquery open div with containing li class=“active”

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently use this code to hide and display a div:

```
<div id="showmenu">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;"><ul><li>Button1</li><li>Button2</li><li>Button3</li></ul></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

When clicking on the div "Click Here" with id="showmenu", I want to add the class "active" to this div.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```
$('#showmenu').click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass("active");
    $('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showmenu">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;"><ul><li>Button1</li><li>Button2</li><li>Button3</li></ul></div>
```

To add/remove the class on each click, use [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showmenu').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('.menu').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:green;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showmenu">Click Here</div>
<div class="menu" style="display: none;"><ul><li>Button1</li><li>Button2</li><li>Button3</li></ul></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it must also remove the active class when closing the div, by clicking again. How can I fix that?